# Undefined method permit

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am practicing the posts in rails guide. In comments controller I write like this but it     comes to error

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:commenter, :body))
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to follow up this [guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)

This should work:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comment = @article.comments.create(comment_params)
    redirect_to article_path(@article)
  end

  private
    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:commenter, :body)
    end
end
```